# Change sql Get date to format ccmmdd?

Tags: sql, substring, date-format, getdate

I am trying to find out how to change my get date into the format of ccmmdd?

So far the closest iv come is ccyymmdd with:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)
```

This produces 20140505, What i'm looking for is 140505.

Is there a link i can follow to see the different sql date formats, or would this be best done through string manipulation?

Comment: @Guneli SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),12)
```

The list of available formats can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Yeah thanks that works, iv also just found RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112),6) that also works.

Comment: Is there a list some where where you can see all the format changes the number after the GETDATE(), xx displays?

Comment: Great thanks, ill be sure to come back to this question in the future to review that list.

Answer (score 0):

This also works.

RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),112),6)